# Regular expression for the specific format (Valid Decimal digits enclosed in left and right parenthesis)

Tags: javascript, regex

We need a regular expression which should accept a valid decimal digits upto 2 decimal points with option of it being enclosed in left and right parenthesis

Valid Examples : 
45.78
99.34
12202.45
(45.22)
(65.00)
(1255.00)

Could any one help us out on this.

Comment: Read up on regular expressions, take a stab at it, and if you get stuck, post your attempt, your reasoning, your test data, and your results, and ask about those.

Comment: We have done our research and got the expression [^0-9\.()] However its allowing us to enter multiple instances of dot , left parenthesis and right parenthesis. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

```
^(\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?)$|^(\(\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?\))$
```

[Regex Test](https://www.regex101.com/r/yR3bA3/1)

#### What matches

- 50
- 50.00
- (50)
- (50.00)

#### Explanation

```
^    //Start of string
    (   // Start capturing group
        \d+ // Digit 1 or more times
        (?: // Start Non capturing group
            \. // Dot
            \d{1,2} // Digit 1 to 2 times
         )? // End non capturing group and ? means conditional
    )   // End capturing group
$    //End of string
    | //OR (Now we check for numbers enclosed in parenthesis)
^    //Start of string
    (   // Start capturing group 
        \( // Match Left Parenthesis
        \d+(?:\.\d{1,2})? // Same as above
        \) // Match Right Parenthesis
    )   // End capturing group
$    //End of string
```

Comment: Its Working however its taking ((500.00) as a valid one. There should not be multiple instances of left or right parenthesis.

Comment: Yes its working now. Thanks. Can you please edit it to accept digits also for example 45 or (56)

Comment: The regular expression looks fine however its not working inside JQuery code failing for (50) (44.22). First expression its validating for example 30 20 66. Please help.